# How to open a .pcb file

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I have a `.pcb` file which is prepared on Protel. I want open this PCB file in Ubuntu 12.04 via using Geda or other applications. However, I could not manage it. How can I see or convert this file in Ubuntu 12.04?

NOTE: I have tried:

- Eagle
- Fritzing
- gEDA
- kiCAD

However, they could not manage to open it.

Comment: maybe type in terminal: `xdg-open nameoffile.pcb`

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of .pcb tools in Ubuntu that you can use to see that file:

Leon

Leon Heller

G1HSM

Kicad - looks pretty good, info [here](http://basicubuntu.blogspot.pt/2009/02/installing-kicad-on-ubuntu.html)

> sudo apt-get install kicad

gEDA

[EAGLE](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/) from CADSOFT

Altium

## Instalation for Altium (Wine is required)

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install wine1.5

wine1.5 is beta version, if you want stable choose wine1.4

After Wine is installed, download Altium and install it normally, like you woould on windows.

Altium Designer 10 is reported working in [WineHq](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22939).

[Circad](http://www.holophase.com) demo

Comment: Altium is working. Please, improve your answer in order to show how to download & install the Altium.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but here we go. You could try **gEDA** which is a truly open source electronics development application (EDA):

```
sudo apt-get install geda geda-utils geda-xgsch2pcb
```

This installs the pcb utility, you just have to double click the `.pdb` file.
It might be possble you have to open a `.pcb` file with **KiCAD** if it is made in that software.

If you would like to open the file in **eagle** you have to convert it to `.brd`